# Performing actions in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm having a bit of trouble comprehending how fragments interact with activities.

I have my main activity that adds a fragment. The fragment class called is here:

```
public class Timer_fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer_frag, container, false);
    }
}
```

The layout being inflated has a textView inside of it, but inside of the fragment class I can't "access" it.

Why can't I add `TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pwd_status);` below the return statement?

This makes sense to me because if I want to add the timer in a bunch of places and change one thing programatically, it would change everywhere. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

### Answer:

I just kept my onCreateView the same and added onActivityCreated. Then I am able to do everything as usual.

Comment: What do you mean "why can't I add it below the return statement"? The `return` should be the very last statement in the method, so of course you can't add that line of code "below the return statement"...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timer_frag, container, false);

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pwd_status);
    /* set the TextView's text, click listeners, etc. */

    return v;
}
```

This will work assuming you have a `TextView` with id `pwd_status` in your `timer_frag` layout.

Comment: Why does this work? Seems like such a simple "workaround" or "loophole" to make it work. This seems that it will allow me to turn my entire one layout one activity application into a fragment that can be used. Correct?

Comment: Why do you think it is a loophole/workaround? The reason why it works is because `Fragment`s have their own separate layouts.

Comment: You could also call `findViewById(R.id.pwd_status)` in `onActivityCreated`. `onActivityCreated` always comes after `onCreateView`, which means the layout will always be inflated at this point... so it is safe to call `findViewById` there.

Comment: Alright, so it seems that my thought process was all wrong. I really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: The `Activity` holds the `Fragment`, but will often know *nothing* about the actual UI components contained within the `Fragment`.

Comment: So how do I "access" the UI components in the fragment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14636/discussion-between-eghdk-and-alex-lockwood)